# Computational complexity of expanding a vector using its index in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, time-complexity

suppose I have a n-by-1 vector A, and a m-by-1 all integer vector b, where max(b)<=n, min(b)>0. Can anyone tell me what is the computational complexity (in big-O notation) for performing command **A(b)** in MATLAB?

Comment: For the record, what you're referring to is known as [linear indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511)

Answer (score 0):

As I found and get a test from `A` with `n = 100, 1000, 10^4, ..., 10^7` and `m = 100` which `A` and `b` generated randomly, average time on the same machine for all case of `n` are the same (also, approximately, all times are the same, and equail to `5.00679e-05` for `A(b)`). Part of the code is like below (**you should be aware that to get the more accurate, you should run in 100 times and get an average. Also, get the variance to see that values are not so different**):

```
A = randi(100,100,1);
b = randi(100,100,1);
tic; A(b); toc
> Elapsed time is 5.38826e-05 seconds.

A = randi(100,1000,1);
b = randi(100,100,1);
tic; A(b); toc
> Elapsed time is 6.31809e-05 seconds.

A = randi(100,10000,1);
b = randi(100,100,1);
tic; A(b); toc
> Elapsed time is 4.88758e-05 seconds.
...

% Also, as you can see the range of the b is growth, base on the size of A
% However, I can't see any changes in the time complexity scale.
A = randi(100,1000000,1);
b = randi(1000000,100,1);
tic; A(b); toc
> Elapsed time is 6.60419e-05 seconds.    
6.60419e-05
```

Also, run test over `n = 100` and `m = 10000, 10^4, ..., 10^7`, and on each run I got `10^-5`, `10^-4`, and so on. In this way, run this on different `n`, and I got the same result. In the below as the same as the previous part, you can follow the following:

```
A = randi(100,100,1);
b = randi(100,10000,1);
tic;A(b);toc
> Elapsed time is 7.00951e-05 seconds.

A = randi(100,100,1);
b = randi(100,100000,1);
tic;A(b);toc
> Elapsed time is 0.000529051 seconds.

A = randi(100,100,1);
b = randi(100,1000000,1);
tic;A(b);toc
> Elapsed time is 0.00533104 seconds.
...
```

For the case of be more aacurate, you can run the code like the following:

```
a = zeros(100,1);
for idx = 1:100
    A = randi(100,100,1);b = randi(100,100000,1);
    tic; A(b);a(idx) = toc;
end 
var(a)
> ans =  4.4092e-10 % very little
mean(a)
> ans = 3.6702e-04 % 10^-4 scale
```

As you can see, the variance is very little, and mean scale is `10^-4`. Hence, you can approve the others by the same method.

Therefore, base on the above analysis and common index methods, We can say the time complexity is not dependent on `n` and dependent on size of the `b`. In sum, the time complexity is `O(m)`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've added for the first case. For the second part which `m` is dynamic, I've written the time scales (`10^-5`, `10^-4`, ...).

Comment: No I meant, show the code and the accurate results, not approximate. **Reproducibility**

Comment: In your test, you make A bigger when m increases, but you do not increase the maximum random number in b, hence only the first 100 elements of A can be indexed into. -- Do you get the same results (and lack of complexitiy in the size of A) if you allow any value from A to be drawn?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin good point. Ya, I've tested. It's added to the example.

Answer (score 0):

## The complexity is 'unusual'

I came up with a short test script, and ran it a few times. If the size of B increases, there is a clear increase in the required time. However, the results get confusing if you look at the size of A.

```
R = zeros(3,4);
for m = 10.^[4 5 6]
   mc = mc+1;
   nc =0;
   for n = 10.^[1 2 3 4]
        nc = nc+1;
        A = rand(m,1);
        b = randi(m, n, 1);
        tic; A(b); R(mc,nc) = toc*10^5;
    end
end
R
```

The above script gave the following results (also similar results when repeated). Note that this was in Octave Online, rather than Matlab.

```
R =

    3.2902    1.7881    2.3127    9.3937
    5.3167    2.0027    2.8133    8.2970
   21.6007    3.3140    4.9829   17.3092
```